# script not updating foodBar UI - roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

So for starters I have

playerStats (module script) game.StarterPlayer.StarterCharacterScripts

```
local module = {}

module.hunger = 0
module.thirst = 100

return module
```

In order for you to not start losing health hunger OR thirst has to be above 0. Right now I have it at zero so I can test the food item that I made that is suppose to add 20 hunger. That does work and stops health loss, BUT it does not update the foodBar UI. (I don't have anything for thirst yet).

The script I have for updating screen and the food item is:

food item (server-side) workspace.Food.ClickDetector

```
local food = script.Parent.Parent
local PlayerStats = require(game.StarterPlayer.StarterCharacterScripts.playerStats)
local gain = 2
local playerFunctions = require(game.StarterPlayer.StarterCharacterScripts.playerFunctions)

script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function() 
    food:remove()
    PlayerStats.hunger+=gain
    print("Food on click : " .. PlayerStats.hunger)
    playerFunctions.updateFood()
end)
```

update foodBar (module script) game.StarterPlayer.StarterCharacterScripts

```
local module = {}

module.updateFood = function() 
    local gui = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui
    local PlayerStats = require(game.StarterPlayer.StarterCharacterScripts.playerStats)
    gui.foodBar.Text = "Hunger: " .. PlayerStats.hunger
end

return module
```

I don't think its the function to update the foodbar because it works at the start in my other script used to check the player stats

```
local data = require(game.StarterPlayer.StarterCharacterScripts.playerStats)
local player = script.Parent
local humanoid = player:WaitForChild("Humanoid");
local playerFunctions = require(script.Parent.playerFunctions)

task.spawn(function()
    while data.hunger <= 0 or data.thirst <= 0 do
        wait(0.1)
        humanoid.Health-=1
    end
end)

humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    data.hunger = 100
    data.thirst = 100
end)

while true do
    wait(0.1)
    playerFunctions.updateFood()
end
```

Yes, I know I put a lot of code here, but I am very new to Lua and have no idea of what this could possibly be so I wanted to make sure you could see everything just in case its something unexpecting.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the hunger bar does not update is because you're updating `StarterGui` (the instance that gives out the Gui) instead of `PlayerGui` (PlayerGui is inside the Player's instance)
Also, don't update the `playerStats` module inside `StarterPlayer`, it will give those stats to all players. Instead, update the module inside of `PlayerScripts` (which is also located inside of the Player's instance) and require that module instead.

Comment: I dont understand what your saying. How would I even access the player instance from a server-side script. Also how am I suppose to update my `playerStats` module inside `PlayerScripts`?

Comment: @SolarFlare you can access it by constantly going to the parent until you reach the player instance. example: your script is inside Player.PlayerGui.Gui.Script, you'll have to do script.Parent.Parent.Parent to reach the player instance. if the thing does not have the Player instance as a descendant, but the character, you can use Players.GetPlayerFromCharacter

Comment: I still don't understand what im suppose to do. How would I even get a script inside `Player.PlayerGui.Gui.Script` in roblox studio? I dont think `Player.PlayerGui.Gui.Script` event exists in `workspace` or `game`

Comment: @SolarFlare all player instances are inside the Players service and to get a script/gui inside PlayerGui, place it inside the StarterGui service